# Selenium printing something different text from expected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to get the US pronunciation from Cambridge Dictionary my code so far is here:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from YDSData import tdata, dummydata

words = dummydata
link='https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for word in words:
    driver.get(link+"/"+str(i))
    try:
        result = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[3]/span')
        print(content)
    except:
      driver.close()
```

This code supposed to give me the US pronunciation on Cambridge dictionary but it prints:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="6f609e22-76ab-443d-8216-4ac90aefda20")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="c7d8a664-d162-4d2c-8c87-dd8e10211024")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="7f163600-d25f-4000-893f-44693736ed41")>]
```

also, it is extremely slow is something wrong with the code?

EDIT:

I've rewritten the code in the answers section to figure out the problem now the code looks like:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from YDSData import tdata, dummydata

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dictionary")

print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='us']//following-sibling::span[@class='pron dpron']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

It works but it took 8 minutes for the code to work giving these errors:

```
[5836:11428:0223/004955.530:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -201
[11580:7744:0223/005141.150:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is 
[14788:5864:0223/005241.189:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[14788:5864:0223/005241.197:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[14788:5864:0223/005241.215:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[14788:5864:0223/005241.243:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
[14788:11300:0223/005241.291:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [00:52:41.291] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Comment: result.text is what your going for and driver.find_element.

Comment: Your xpath is also not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="6f609e22-76ab-443d-8216-4ac90aefda20")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="c7d8a664-d162-4d2c-8c87-dd8e10211024")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="285ac250c8925dd19eb01a7853c1f219", element="7f163600-d25f-4000-893f-44693736ed41")>]
```

the [WebElements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) when you print them on the console.

---

To print the text ***/ˈdɪk.ʃən.er.i/*** you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dictionary")
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='us']//following-sibling::span[@class='pron dpron']").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***/ˈdɪk.ʃən.er.i/*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dictionary")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='us']//following-sibling::span[@class='pron dpron']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  /ˈdɪk.ʃən.er.i/
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

Comment: Hello, it works the way I wanted but there is a slight problem so I edited my question. If you think it is solvable, I'd appreciate it. If not thanks for teaching me thus far!

Comment: @Aschente Each console error have a different reason and history. You can start with [Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71165579/7429447) and then move to [USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70476264/7429447)